# Change servlet mapping depending on Tomcat context

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'd like to assign a different default servlet when inside a particular Tomcat context.

For example, when inside my root context, I want to use the following servlet mapping:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But when inside a context located on path `/img-data`, I want to use:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application runs in servlet 3.0+ container you could use a `ServletContextListener` to dynamically set the default servlet, depending on the context path.

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();
        if ("".equals(sc.getContextPath())) {
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dreg = sc.addServlet("pageservlet", new PageServlet());
            dreg.addMapping("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asked a follow up question, but think I figured it out (deleted it).  Thanks a lot for this answer.